# Does Firebase have an API for importing/exporting users in the email-password auth db?

Tags: firebase

I know I can add/delete users using the GUI, but I was hoping we could do that in bulk via an API call, similar to what we already can do with the security rules.

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing API for doing this in bulk, but you could do this on your local client, in the browser, by loading your dataset via JSON and looping through calls to `createUser()`. I would expect this is be very fast and satisfy your use case.